# How to get the specific child window with python selenium firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

When there is only one window opened, I will simply use bellow to get the child window:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.a.com')
handles = browser.window_handles
parent_a = browser.current_window_handle
browser.execute_script('window.open("http://www.a1.com");')
new_handles = browser.window_handles
child_a = new_handles[-1]
```

However, when several new windows opened at the same time, how to get the parent_a's child window?
The child window's url and title is unknown.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.a.com')
handles = browser.window_handles
parent_a = browser.current_window_handle
browser.execute_script('window.open("http://www.a.com");')
parent_b = browser.window_handles[-1]
```

www.a.com will open new windows and close it automatically.
how to get parent_a.children and parent_b.children.

http://www.a.com's source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin=window.open('random-url');
sleep(randomtime);
newWin.close();
</script>
</head>
<body>
body content
</body>
</html>
```

With javascript you can get save the new opened window, so it's not the problem.

```
var child = window.open('http://www.b.com')
parent = child.openner
```

Comment: `parent_a` can have multiple child windows opened at the same time which you can traverse using the `window_handle`. So where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: @DebanjanB the new windows are not opened from the same parent

Comment: Doesn't matters from where the new windows/tabs are getting opened. You can always grab the new `window_handle` to traverse to it and come back to previous.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i don't make the question clear, I updated it, please help me with it.

Comment: Can you update the Question with your exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate?